# Can I get a variable into ngFor using async pipe?

Tags: javascript, angular

There my (normalized) state:

```
export class State {
    chatIDs: string[];
    chats: { [chatID:string]: Chat };
}
```

Trying to loop through chats (state as Observable) in some component template:

```
<div *ngFor="let chatID of (state$ | async).chatIDs; 
             let currentChat = (state$ | async).chats[chatID]">
   <!---->
</div>
```

The string `let currentChat = (state$ | async).chats[chatID]` throws error:

> unexpected token (, expected identifier, keyword, or string

How can I get a reference to the current chat into the loop? It's possible, for e.g., as child component with the input `(state$ | async).chats[chatID]`. But is there way more elegant (without creating any new components)?

Angular v2.4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `*ngIf` directive to first check then you use `*ngFor` to iterate the chats.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/Observable";
import { Subscriber } from "rxjs/Subscriber";

export class Chat {
  message: string
  constructor(message: string) {
    this.message = message;
  }
}



export class State {
  chatIDs: string[];
  chats: {
    [chatID: string]: Chat
  };
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  state: any;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.state = new Observable<State>((observer: Subscriber<State>) => {
      setInterval(() => {
        let state = new State();
        state.chatIDs = ['1', '2', '3'];
        state.chats = {
          '1': new Chat('Chat 1'),
          '2': new Chat('Chat 2'),
          '3': new Chat('Chate 3')
        }
        observer.next(state)
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

Put variable s in scope using *ngIf:

```
<div *ngIf="state | async; let s">
  <div *ngFor="let id of s?.chatIDs">
    {{ s?.chats[id] | json }}
  </div>
</div>
```